# Shell script commands not executed after SSH login until exit from SSH

Tags: ssh, shell-script

I'm new to shell scripting and I tried to have a script ssh into another machine and perform some commands. I have the public/private key set up so I'm not prompted for a password when I ssh into the other machine manually. The problem is that the scripts stops after sshing into the other machine unless the ssh is exited. In the code below, the second and third line are not ex

```
ssh usr@myserver.com 'installmyprogram.sh'
echo "Successfully logged in?"
pwd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way shell scripts work. Given a file with

```
ssh usr@myserver.com 'installmyprogram.sh'
echo "Successfully logged in?"
pwd
```

First the shell executes the command on the first line, when that command is finished, it executes the command on the second line.

You may want to do something like this (untested)

```
ssh usr@myserver.com 'installmyprogram.sh; echo "Successfully logged in?"; pwd'
```